# Update a column in a table from other table with 6billion rows in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g

I have 2 table Table A, Table B. Both the tables are of size 500GB, Some of the columns of tables are as below.

### Table A

- ID
- Type
- DateModified

Added a new column to Table as CID, which is available in Table B.

### Table B

- ID
- CID
- DateGenerated

Table A is partitioned on dateModified, Table B is not partitioned, My task is to get the CID from Table B and update it in Table A. Both the tables are having billions of records.

I have tried Merge/SQL but its too slow, which cannot be completed in 2 days.

Comment: Perhaps showing your merge statement and the explain plan for it might help. Are you sure it was still working and wasn't blocked on a row locked in another session? If A and B are related, why copy the value in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a new column to an existing table causing row fragmentation. Updating the new column to some value will probably cause massive row chaining, partitioned or not. And yes, that is slow, even when there are sufficient indexes etc.

Recommended approach:

- You are on Enterprise Edition since you have partitioning, so you might be able to solve this using the schema versions functionality.
- But if this is a one time action and you do not know how to use it well, I would use a "create table ... as" approach. Building the table from scratch and then switching it when ready. Take care to not miss any trickle loaded transactions. With partitioning it will be fast (writing 500 GB at say 50 MB/sec on a strong server is not unrealistic, taking 3 hours).